# How do I use popover from Twitter Bootstrap to display an image?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

The canonical example for Twitter Bootstrap's popover feature is sort of a tooltip on steroids with a title.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="blob" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A title">hover for popover</a>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$("#blob").popover({offset: 10});
</script>
```

I'd like to use popover to display an image.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please refer to this link. By using this I think you should able to display image also. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494291/can-i-use-html-tags-in-twitter-bootstrap-popover-
data-content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494291/can-i-use-html-tags-in-twitter-bootstrap-popover-data-content)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Very simple :)

```
<a href="#" id="blob" class="btn large primary" rel="popover">hover for popover</a>

var img = '<img src="https://si0.twimg.com/a/1339639284/images/three_circles/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" />';

$("#blob").popover({ title: 'Look! A bird!', content: img, html:true });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weuWk/

Comment: `html:true` is required to make the html being rendered correctly :(

Comment: Worked for me after adding `trigger: 'hover'`

Answer (score 14):

Sort of similar to what mattbtay said, but a few changes. needed html:true. 
Put this script on bottom of the page towards close body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("[rel=drevil]").popover({
      placement : 'bottom', //placement of the popover. also can use top, bottom, left or right
      title : '<div style="text-align:center; color:red; text-decoration:underline; font-size:14px;"> Muah ha ha</div>', //this is the top title bar of the popover. add some basic css
      html: 'true', //needed to show html of course
      content : '<div id="popOverBox"><img src="http://www.hd-report.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/mr-evil.jpg" width="251" height="201" /></div>' //this is the content of the html box. add the image here or anything you want really.
});
});
</script>
```

Then HTML is:

```
<a href="#" rel="drevil">mischief</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

simple with generated links  :)
html:

```
<span class='preview' data-image-url="imageUrl.png" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" >preview</span>
```

js:

```
$('.preview').popover({
    'trigger':'hover',
    'html':true,
    'content':function(){
        return "<img src='"+$(this).data('imageUrl')+"'>";
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A4zHC/

Answer (score 6):

This is what I used.

```
$('#foo').popover({
    placement : 'bottom',
    title : 'Title',
    content : '<div id="popOverBox"><img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01515/alGore_1515233c.jpg" /></div>'
});
```

and for the HTML

```
<b id="foo" rel="popover">text goes here</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have an example of Bootstrap 3 popover showing an image with the tittle above it when the mouse hovers over some text. I've put in some inline styling that you may want to take out or change.....

This also works pretty well on mobile devices because the image will popup on the first tap and the link will open on the second.
html:

```
<h5><a href="#" title="Solid Tiles Template" target="_blank" data-image-url="http://s29.postimg.org/t5pik8lyf/tiles1_preview.jpg" class="preview" rel="popover" style="color: green; font-style: normal; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 16px;">Template Preview 1 <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a></h5>

<h5><a href="#" title="Clear Tiles Template" target="_blank" data-image-url="http://s9.postimg.org/rdonet7jj/tiles2_2_preview.jpg" class="preview" rel="popover" style="color: red; font-style: normal; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 16px;">Template Preview 2 <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a></h5>

<h5><a href="#" title="Clear Tiles Template" target="_blank" data-image-url="http://s27.postimg.org/8scrcdu9v/tiles3_3_preview.jpg" class="preview" rel="popover" style="color: blue; font-style: normal; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 16px;">Template Preview 3 <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a></h5>
```

js:

```
$('.preview').popover({
    'trigger':'hover',
    'html':true,
    'content':function(){
        return "<img src='"+$(this).data('imageUrl')+"'>";
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pepsimax_uk/myk38781/3/

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: sure. what would you like to know?

Comment: Great answer. It may be worth nothing that if you are using AngularJS, the JavaScript needs to be included in the controller initialization callback or it won't work.