# Django Templateview - Loading HTML table with Boostrap Popovers not working

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

[image]When rendering this template. The html is correct, and the html table loads correctly. But I have put special pop-over attributes to some cells. These do not work after loading the html `TemplateView` from a ajax request on the same page.

I have literally copied the exactly original template html for the html table and javascript, from the **basehtml.html** and put it into **servicepathtable_html_table.html**. Everything loads in the view including the Datatable. Search functionality and sorting work, but the popup and hover overs don't work. I know that the table html itself is being rendered correctly. As the correct field is highlighted green using a html attribute for that `<td>`

I'm thinking it has to do something with reloading the DOM or at least having the DOM recognize the new html. Any help on getting the popovers to "work" would be greatly appreciated.

**Ajax Request**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/servicepathapi/v1/servicepathtable_html/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function(result) {
      $('#s1').html(result);
      $.smallBox({
        title : "Table Loaded Successfully",
        content :
        "The API Works",
        color : "#79C1E4",
        timeout: 10000,
        icon : "fa fa-thumbs-up",
      });
        console.log(result)

    }
});
```

**basehtml.html**:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="s1">
</div>
```

**views.py**:

```
class Servicepathtable_html_table(TemplateView):

    template_name = "servicepathtable_html_table.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Servicepathtable_html_table, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        enddate = date.today()
        startdate = enddate - timedelta(days=4)
        service_path_recents = ServicePathTableFull.objects.filter(date__range=[startdate, enddate])
        recent_service_names = [x.service_path_name for x in service_path_recents]
        service_path_created_recent = ServicePathTableFull.objects.filter(date_created__range=[startdate, enddate])
        created_recent_service_names = [x.service_path_name for x in service_path_created_recent]

        for service in created_recent_service_names:
            if service in recent_service_names:
                recent_service_names.remove(service)

        context['service_path_table'] = ServicePathTableFull.objects.all()
        context['service_paths'] = ServicePathPaths.objects.all()
        context['recent_service_names'] = recent_service_names
        context['service_path_recents'] = service_path_recents
        context['created_recent_service_names'] = created_recent_service_names
        return context
```

**servicepathtable_html_table.html**:

```
{% load service_path_extras %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<div class = "well well-light">
<div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-blueDark" id="wid-id-5" data-widget-editbutton="false">


<!-- widget edit box -->
<div class="jarviswidget-editbox">
  <!-- This area used as dropdown edit box -->

</div>
<!-- end widget edit box -->

<!-- widget content -->
<div class="widget-body no-padding">

  <table id="service_path_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center"data-class="expand" class="col-sm-2"><h1 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Service" data-content="Service is the partition or network segment name for a BU.<br>Click through for historical transitions.<br><br>Services Highlighted in <span class='badge bg-color-yellow'>yellow</span> have transitioned or added within the last 3 days." data-html="true"><strong>Service</strong></h1></th>
        <th style="text-align:center"><h1 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="IP of Service" data-content="The Destination IP address of the corresponding Service<br>is checked from the HUB: hub1: <pre>sh ip bgp x.x.x.x</pre>" data-html="true"><strong>Service IP</strong></h1></th>
        <th style="text-align:center"data-hide="phone"><h1 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Best Path Router Hostname" data-content="The destination Hostname of the best path router. <br>Hover over name for more detail. <br>Click through for Statseeker Device View." data-html="true"><strong>Service Router</strong></h1></th>
        <th style="text-align:center"data-hide="phone"><h1 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Service Path Source Location" data-content="Location of running service. <br>Hover for Alternate Paths." data-html="true"><strong>Service Location</strong></h1></th>
        <th style="text-align:center"data-hide="phone"><h1 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="SNMP Location" data-content="SNMP Location field of the best path router." data-html="true"><strong>Route Detail</strong></h1></th>
        <th style="text-align:center"data-hide="phone,tablet"><h1><strong>Since</strong></h1></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in service_path_table %}
      <tr>
        {% if row.service_path_name in created_recent_service_names %}
        <td align="center" class="success"><h6 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Description" data-content="{{row.service_path_description}}"><strong><a href="/servicepathtable/{{row.service_path_id}}/">{{row.service_path_name}}</a></strong></h6></td>
        {% elif row.service_path_name in recent_service_names %}
        <td align="center" class="warning"><h6 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Description" data-content="{{row.service_path_description}}"><strong><a href="/servicepathtable/{{row.service_path_id}}/">{{row.service_path_name}}</a></strong></h6></td>
        {% else %}
        <td align="center"><h6 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Description" data-content="{{row.service_path_description}}"><strong><a href="/servicepathtable/{{row.service_path_id}}/">{{row.service_path_name}}</a></strong></h6></td>
        {% endif %}
        <td align="center"><h6 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Raw Command Output" data-content="<pre>HTX-JC-HUB-2#{{row.sh_command_output}}</pre>" data-html="true">{{row.service_path_ip}}</td>
        <td align="center"><h6 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="<h4>Quick Router Information</h4>"  data-content="<div class='panel-body no-padding'>
  <table class='table table-bordered table-condensed'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th align='center'>IP</th>
        <th align='center'>Model</th>
        <th>Tunnel Count</th>
        <th>CPU One Minute Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align='center'>{{row.ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.model}}</td>
        <td align='center'>{{row.tunnel_count}}</td>
        <td align='center'>{{row.cpu_uti_last_one_min}}%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>" data-html="true"><a href="http://NIM/cgi/nimc02?sort=&report=116&device={{row.hostname|convert_host}}">{{row.hostname}}</a></h6></td>
        <td align="center"><h6 rel="popover-hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="<h4>Alternate Paths</h4>"  data-content="<div class='panel-body no-padding'>
  <table class='table table-bordered table-condensed'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>jConnect IP</th>
        <th>Pref</th>
        <th>Via IP</th>
        <th>Loopback IP</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% if row.alt_path_0_ip %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_0_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_0_local_pref}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_0_via_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_0_loopback_ip}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
      {% if row.alt_path_1_ip %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_1_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_1_local_pref}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_1_via_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_1_loopback_ip}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
      {% if row.alt_path_2_ip %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_2_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_2_local_pref}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_2_via_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_2_loopback_ip}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
      {% if row.alt_path_3_ip %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_3_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_3_local_pref}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_3_via_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_3_loopback_ip}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
      {% if row.alt_path_4_ip %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_4_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_4_local_pref}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_4_via_ip}}</td>
        <td>{{row.alt_path_4_loopback_ip}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>" data-html="true">{{row.snmp_location|get_city}}</h6></td>
        <td align="center">{{row.snmp_location}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{row.date}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
<!-- end widget content -->

</div>
<!-- end widget div -->
</div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var responsiveHelper_dt_basic = undefined;
  var responsiveHelper_datatable_fixed_column = undefined;
  var responsiveHelper_datatable_col_reorder = undefined;
  var responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools = undefined;

  var breakpointDefinition = {
    tablet : 1024,
    phone : 480
  };

  /* TABLETOOLS */
  $('#service_path_table').dataTable({

  // Tabletools options:
  //   https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options
  "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-6 hidden-xs'T>r>"+
      "t"+
      "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12'p>>",
  "bPaginate": false,
      "oTableTools": {

    "aButtons": [
              {
                  "sExtends": "xls",
                  "sTitle": "ETS_Service_Path_Table",
              },
      {
                  "sExtends": "pdf",
                  "sTitle": "ETS_Service_Path_Table",
                  "sPdfMessage": "Service Path Table PDF",
                  "sPdfSize": "letter"
              },
    {
      "sExtends": "copy",
      "sButtonText": "Copy to Clipboard",
      "oSelectorOpts": { filter: "applied", order: "current" }
    },
    {
      "sExtends": "csv",
      "sButtonText": "Export to CSV",
      "sTitle": "ETS_Service_Path_Table",
      "oSelectorOpts": { filter: "applied", order: "current" }
    },
    {
      "sExtends": "print",
      "sButtonText": "Print",
      "oSelectorOpts": { filter: "applied", order: "current" }
    }
         ],
          "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
      },
  "autoWidth" : true,
  "preDrawCallback" : function() {
    // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
    if (!responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools) {
      responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#service_path_table'), breakpointDefinition);
    }
  },
  "rowCallback" : function(nRow) {
    responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools.createExpandIcon(nRow);
  },
  "drawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
    responsiveHelper_datatable_tabletools.respond();
  }
  });

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, I had to "reinitialize" everything marked as "popup-hover" AFTER I replaced the html.

Add `$("[rel=popover-hover]").popover({'trigger':'hover'});`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#put_new").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/servicepathapi/v1/servicepathtable_html/",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result) {
              $('#s1').html(result);
              $("[rel=popover-hover]").popover({'trigger':'hover'});
              $.smallBox({
                title : "Table Loaded Successfully",
                content :
                "The API Works",
                color : "#79C1E4",
                timeout: 10000,
                icon : "fa fa-thumbs-up",
              });
                console.log(result)

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Kuddos to this question: [How do I use popover from Twitter Bootstrap to display an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075560/how-do-i-use-popover-from-twitter-bootstrap-to-display-an-image)