# Popover for long text without spaces

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have in grid in one column long text which should be truncated in grid (ends with ...) but should show whole in popover.

The popover is displaying correctly when there are spaces in my text. For text with no spaces popover is displaying incorrectly. See examples below

Incorrect popover:

[image: Incorrect popover]

Correct popover:

[image: Correct popover]

I'm displaying popover in that way:

```
<div data-toggle="popover" rel="popover"
    data-container="body" data-content="My_test_in_popover">
    My_text_with_...
</div>
```

How should I modified code to display popover correctly for long text with no spaces?

Comment: check to this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: apply css word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's because Twitter bootstrap applies a [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) property to the `.popover` box by default (Which is `max-width: 276px;`).

There are two options:

**1)** Override the `max-width` by reseting that to `none` as:

```css
.popover {
    max-width: none;
}
```

**2)** Or use [`word-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) CSS declaration for the popover content box as:

```css
.popover-content {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: This approach worked for me too although I had to use "tooltip" and "tooltip-inner" in bootstrap 3. See the markup section in...
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-tooltip-multiline

Comment: Tooltip and Popover are two different things in bootstrap. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843249/twitter-bootstrap-popover-vs-tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Since 2012 another solution for word-wrap is:

`overflow-wrap:anywhere;`

More information: [Difference between overflow-wrap and word-break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259916/difference-between-overflow-wrap-and-word-break)

Examples of use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

edit: word-break: break-word is officially deprecated; see https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#valdef-word-break-break-word